# Why doesn't work radio play on read iWatch?

Tags: audio, playback

I have developed radio station play app on iOS.
It works well on simulator.
But it doesn't work on real device.
Can you please let me know the reason?
Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Media on iWatch needs wireless ear pods or Bluetooth speaker to hear it. The watch speaker does not play media.

Comment: But it's played on watch simulation.

Comment: I don't need to hear with Speaker.
I gonna to use airpods.

Comment: was my answer helpful? Did you manage to do this?

Comment: No, sorry, it didn't help me.
I don't try to hear with the watch speaker.

Comment: Hello Jabbar
If a Watch Speaker doesn't play a media, it's able to play an Audio?